# Source for high-res subscription imagery service

Tags: data, imagery, web-service, united-states

I'm developing a diagramming tool using aerial imagery as a reference layer. This tool should allow the user to zoom in quite close to a roadway or intersection. Unfortunately none of the public map services I have tested supports zooming in close enough. Are there subscription map services out there that have imagery with resolution high enough to zoom in quite close to the roadway?

Comment: What Region,Area or Country are you wanting High Res imagery for?

Comment: Florida state-wide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be worth while to check out GeoEye, or alternatively NearMap (not sure if this works outside of Australia, but works with OSM XML connectors)

http://www.geoeye.com/CorpSite/

http://www.nearmap.com/

---

1/10/2010: NearMap does seem to only have some High Res imagery in Australia.

Comment: http://go.nearmap.com/coverage suggests that NearMap is also available in the US - I suspect that availability is more recent than your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The USGS seems to have 1ft imagery for all (most, many) of Florida's counties. They are available via WMS from http://imsortho.cr.usgs.gov/WMS_Capabilities/USGS_EDC_Ortho_Florida/capabilities_1_1_1.xml?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=getcapabilities

Answer (score 1):

There also is the [ImageConnect](http://www.digitalglobe.com/index.php/48/Products?product_id=19) service from Digital Globe. Spot Image is also preparing a similar service, SPOTMaps online, but I couldn't find a reference yet. Both are, will be, available as WMS.

Answer (score 0):

ESRI World Imagery service can be added to ArcMap as a base map layer and has a decent coverage of (1-meter or better) satellite imagery for most urban areas in North America.

Comment: That's the one I've been using, but it doesn't allow us to zoom in quite close enough.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mapwise.com/maps/florida/aerial-photo-satellite.html

http://aerialsexpress.com/coverage.aspx#lnkStates

Answer (score -1):

You can purchase aerial photos of the entire state of Florida here:

Beverly Renard
Technology Specialist
FREAC/Florida State University
C2200 University Center
296 Champions Way
P.O. Box 3062641
Tallahassee, FL 32306-2641
850-644-2305
850-644-7360 fax

That will get you over 300 GB of MrSID files. Then you need to setup the infrastructure to serve those images.